# How to autowire a service in Spring Boot and pass dynamic parameters to the constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor, autowired

I'm working on a Spring Boot project and I'm facing some issues when trying to autowire a Service. This is my current code:

```
@Component
public class StealFromPocket implements Command {
    private Integer gameId;
    private Player playerFrom;

    @Autowired
    GameService gameService;

    public StealFromPocket(Integer gameId, Player playerFrom) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.playerFrom = playerFrom;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        gameService.findPlayersByGameId(gameId).forEach(player -> {
            new StealCoinCommand(playerFrom, player).execute();
        });

    }
}
```

The constructor parameters `gameId` and `playerFrom` are known at runtime, so I can't hardcode them or store them in a configuration file.

This is the place where `StealFromPocket` is being instantiated from a `service` via reflection (`completeClassName` will change depending on user interaction. In this example, it would be `org.springframework...StealFromPocket`:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(completeClassName);
Object card = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Integer.class, Player.class).newInstance(gameId, playerFrom);
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("execute");
method.invoke(card);
```

When trying to build the project, I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.ntfh.cardlogic.abilitycard.rogue.RobarBolsillos required a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' in your configuration.
```

I believe the problem is that I am not passing `GameService` as a constructor parameter, but due to the nature of my project, these services cannot be passed as parameters since they will be different depending on the class instantiated via reflection.

Comment: instead of calling "method.invoke" you can create a function inside GameService which takes card object and then you can move to logic inside that function and call it like "gameService.invoke(card)" after instantiating card object. This allows you to remove GameService field in your Command classes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The point of having separate class was to decouple the logic of these two components since there will be around 50 classes like ```StealFromPocket```, each one with its own logic and service dependencies, so having it all in the ```GameService``` class would make it quite big and hard to understand.

Comment: I dont think that spring can inject the autowired bean when you try to instantiate with new keyword or via reflection, but you can try to remove "@Autowired" from "GameService" field but keep it as a field in that class , after that you accept 2 constructor arguments which is "gameId" and "playerForm"

Comment: when you call "newInstance" method compiler shouldn't complain about instantiating because "GameService" has not "@Autowired" anymore and not in the constructor, so you can get that bean from "applicationContext" after instantiating the card and call "card.setGameService(gameService)" , you have "gameService" set in this object. so you can call the method invocation now. Let me know if that works

Comment: you probably need to add "setGameService" method to your "Command" interface btw

Comment: This solutions is fine considering that ```GameService``` is the only service that is going to be used. However, given that there will be so many classes of the type of ```StealFromPocket``` but using different services inside, this is not a possibility.

Comment: I also thought about only having ```@Autowired GameService gameService``` as an attribute and passing the rest as ```execute(Integer gameId, Player playerFrom)``` parameters but ```gameService``` is not being injected, I suppose because I am creating a ```new StealFromPocket()``` in the reflection part. I don't really know how can I approach this.

Comment: yes thats because of reflection, either you have to autowire all other services in a class which has reflection part and then set services via setters or move to "execute" logic to this class, in the first approach you can use custom annotations like "@CustomService GameService gameService ... " then iterate card object fields via reflection in a for loop you can set all of the service fields. for the second approach you have one big class with all autowired dependencies and bunch of methods... i dont have any other solution for the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the implementation of the class so that the `execute` method receives the corresponding parameters, and the autowired fields are the only attributes of the `StealFromPocket` class. Now it looks like this:

```
@Component
public class StealFromPocket {

    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;

    public void execute(Player playerFrom) {
        Integer gameId = playerFrom.getGame().getId();
        gameService.findPlayersByGameId(gameId).forEach(player -> {
            new StealCoinCommand(playerFrom, player).execute();
        });
    }
}
```

And in the `GameService.java` I do the following:

```
// Get the class from its name
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(completeClassName);
// Instantiate an object of the class
Object cardCommand = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
// Autowire the new object's dependencies (services used inside)
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean(cardCommand);
factory.initializeBean(cardCommand, className);
// Get a reference to the method "execute", that receives 2 parameters
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("execute", Player.class);
// Execute the method with the parameters
method.invoke(cardCommand, playerFrom);
```

Comment: factory.autowireBean(cardCommand);
factory.initializeBean(cardCommand, className);  if these lines allow to inject autowired beans , your implementation seems correct.

Comment: Yes, everything is working now, I had to inject the beans manually with those methods since I'm creating a `cardCommand` object using Java's `new` keyword, which does not tell spring to inject the dependencies automatically.